# Is there a built in function to obtain the back diagonal of a matrix?

Tags: matrix

Given the following matrix:

```
m = Array[Subscript[a, #, #2] &, {4, 4}]
```

[image]

how can I find the skew diagonal or anti-diagonal or back diagonal of the matrix (shown in red)

[image]

Comment: What is a "back diagonal"? Do you mean the "skew diagonal" or "anti diagonal"?

Comment: You can try to apply `Reverse` to the matrix before `Diagonal`. The elements will be in reverse order so you might want to apply `Reverse` again to the result...

Comment: Consider `MapThread[Part, {Array[C, {5, 5}], -Range[5]}]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

More options:

```
a = Range@12 ~Partition~ 4;

a // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 9 & 10 & 11 & 12
\end{array}
\right)$

```
Diagonal[Reverse @ a]
```

> ```
> {9, 6, 3}
> ```

```
Diagonal[a ~Reverse~ 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {3, 6, 9}
> ```

```
Diagonal[a ~Reverse~ 2]
```

> ```
> {4, 7, 10}
> ```

```
Diagonal[Reverse @ a, 1]
```

> ```
> {10, 7, 4}
> ```

Answer (score 10):

```
Diagonal[Reverse /@ Array[f, {4, 4}]]
```

> {f[1, 4], f[2, 3], f[3, 2], f[4, 1]}

Comment: ...and if you want the off-antidiagonals, just use the second argument of `Diagonal[]`.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you can take diagonal off a rectangular matrix too. "Back 'diagonal'".

```
SeedRandom[1];
m = RandomInteger[6, {3, 4}]
(* {{6, 4, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 6, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 6}} *)

Table[m[[i, -i]], {i, Min@Dimensions@m}]
(* {4, 6, 2} *)
```

Comment: This is two orders of magnitude faster than what I proposed.  Were I to answer this question today I would use this method. A very belated +1.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a flexible version:

```
antidiag[m_] := Diagonal[m[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, 1 ;; -1 ;; 1]]]
antidiag[m_, offset_] := 
 Diagonal[m[[offset ;; -1, offset ;; -1]][[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, 
   1 ;; -1 ;; 1]]]
```

with no second argument, it gives what you want.

```
MatrixForm[m = Array[Subscript[a, #1, #2] &, {5, 5}]]
antidiag[m]
antidiag[m, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: This is probably the "correct" way to approach it, though perhaps less transparent than `Reverse`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was not aware that you were an advocate of "transparency" :) thanks.

Comment: acl: `transparent~ less~ than`

Comment: @acl Touché! (Most of my coding is quite transparent... to myself.)

Answer (score 3):

If by "back diagonal", you mean the diagonal from the NE corner to the SW corner of the matrix, then you can obtain it the following way:

```
Clear@AntiDiagonal
AntiDiagonal[m_?MatrixQ] /; Equal @@ Dimensions@m := 
    Composition[Reverse, Diagonal, Reverse][m]
```

Comment: If by "NE corner to the SW corner", you mean the top right to the bottom left corner, then you ...  ;-)