# Take both of the diagonals through an element in a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a matrix like this:

```
Reverse@Array[List, {8, 8}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

I need a function that given an element of this matrix will return all the elements corresponding to the two diagonals that run through it.

The first diagonal can be found like this:

```
Diagonal[matrix, j-i]
```

where `{i,j}` is the element. How can I get the diagonal that runs orthogonally to this through the same given element `{i,j}`?

(It is somewhat related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23240/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-obtain-the-back-diagonal-of-a-matrix) question but my problem is more that I can't figure out which diagonal I want once I've reversed the matrix.)

Comment: You mean without `Reverse`, right?

Comment: @Szabolcs There is a reason why my matrix is reversed but I will gladly accept answers that use a matrix that wasn't reversed to begin with.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  I was asking, are you looking for answers which don't use `Reverse`?  I posted an answer which does use reverse.

Comment: @Szabolcs Your solution is fine, actually it is the same kind of solution I attempted but I somehow never got it to work. Look forward to my +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you said, to get the main diagonal through $(i,j)$, you use

```
Diagonal[mat, j - i]
```

To get the other one, you can use

```
Diagonal[Reverse[mat, 2], (Dimensions[mat][[2]] - j + 1) - i]
```

Check correctness visually:

```
{i, j} = {3, 5}
MatrixForm[mat /. ((# -> Style[#, Red]) & /@ Diagonal[mat, j - i])]
MatrixForm[
 mat /. ((# -> Style[#, Red]) & /@ 
    Diagonal[Reverse[mat, 2], (Dimensions[mat][[2]] - j + 1) - i])]
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh... come on. One minute faster??

Comment: @halirutan 1 minute and 53 seconds! :D

Answer (score 11):

The relation for the indices of matrix diagonals is easy to infer, and you can observe this from the following image:

[image]

If $A_{i_0,j_0}=A_{5,3}$ is the chosen element, then the diagonal elements have indices satisfying $i-j = i_0-j_0$ and the skew diagonal elements have indices satisfying $i+j=i_0+j_0$.

The problem is now almost solved! We just feed these exact rules to `SparseArray`:

```
Clear@orthoDiags
orthoDiags[{p_, q_}, n_] := 
    SparseArray[{
        {i_, j_} /; j + i == p + q :> 1, 
        {i_, j_} /; i - j == p - q :> 1}, 
        {n, n}
]
```

and use `Pick` to extract the elements:

```
Flatten@Pick[mat, orthoDiags[{5, 3}, 8], 1]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, had same idea, I think it quite elegant since it can be easily generalized to other "shapes". Well done.

Answer (score 7):

There are many solutions. I like one based on `FrobeniusSolve` (see e.g. this answer [How to find lattice points on a line segment?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16678/how-to-find-lattice-points-on-a-line-segment/16705#16705)):

```
d[i_Integer, j_Integer] /; i > 0 && j > 0 := 
  DeleteCases[ FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, i + j], {___, 0, ___}]
```

Then

```
matrix[[#1, #2]]& @@@ d[3, 4]
```

> ```
> {{8, 6}, {7, 5}, {6, 4}, {5, 3}, {4, 2}, {3, 1}}
> ```

yields that second diagonal orthogonal to `Diagonal[matrix, 4 - 3]`.
But as far as you work with matrices like `matrix` you needn't use neiter `Apply` nor `Part`, one has only to put adequate initial values (equations) to `FrobeniusSolve`.

As an alternative to `d` function one can use diag based on `Array`:

```
diag[i_, j_] := Array[{# + i, j - #} &, i + j - 1, -i + 1]
```

Answer (score 5):

May late entry (called away). Short and sweet I think.

Edit: Ooops, did not read OP closely enough - this works for nXm shapes, not nXmXo...
I'll leave answer for searchers with the former unless OP wants removal. See update below...

```
xDiag[mat_, {er_, ec_}] := 
 SparseArray[{r_, c_} :> mat[[r, c]] /; Abs[r - er] == Abs[c - ec], 
   Dimensions[mat]]["NonzeroValues"]

Row[{(test = Table[10 x + y, {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]) // MatrixForm
  , xDiag[test, {2, 3}]},"  "]
```

[image]

After discovering the flaw in the above (shape limited to nXm, and fails with zero elements in diagonals) came up with one I like even better. It is shape agnostic, that is, it works with any array shape treating "diagonals" at the top level:

```
(* cross diagonals *)
Diag2[mat_, {er_, ec_}] := 
 Join @@ Cases[
   ReplacePart[mat, {r_, c_, ___} /; Abs[r - er] != Abs[c - ec] -> Sequence[]], {__}, {1}]

(* tests *)
Column[{Column[{(test1 = Table[10 x + y, {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]) // 
     MatrixForm, xDiag2[test1, {3, 2}]}, Left, 1],
  Column[{(test2 = Array[List, {5, 5}]) // MatrixForm, 
     xDiag2[test2, {3, 2}]}, Left, 1]
   Column[{(test3 = Array[List, {5, 5, 2}]) // MatrixForm, 
     xDiag2[test3, {3, 2}]}, Left, 1]}, Left, 2]

(* results *)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, using `Diagonal` it should be something like this:

```
extract[m_, {i_, j_}] := 
 {Diagonal[m, j - i], Diagonal[Reverse[m], (i + j) - (Length[m] + 1)]}
```

And then:

```
m = Array[List, {8, 8}];
m // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

you have:

```
extract[m,{6,2}]//Column
(* {{5,1},{6,2},{7,3},{8,4}}
   {{7,1},{6,2},{5,3},{4,4},{3,5},{2,6},{1,7}} *)
```