# How to get all the elements in the opposite diagonal of an element

Tags: matrix

I want to specify an element in a matrix and get all the elements in the diagonal of the element.

For example:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

when I specify an element 7 in the above matrix, I can get all the elements `{4,7,10}` in the reverse diagonal of the element.

When the specified matrix elements have duplicates, the multiple lists of the opposite diagonals of containing the specified element are output.

```
Diagonal[Reverse@({
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
    {9, 10, 11, 12}
   }), 0 - 2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly different formulation and output from [Alan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19530/alan)'s method:

```
fn[a_?MatrixQ, x_] :=
  a ~Reverse~ 2 /. b_ :> (Diagonal[b, #2 - #] & @@@ Position[b, x])
```

Test:

```
Mod[Range@40, 12] ~Partition~ 8 // MatrixForm

fn[%, 7]
```

> $\begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  9 & 10 & 11 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
>  5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 0 \\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  9 & 10 & 11 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
> \end{array}$
>
> ```
> {{7, 2, 9, 4, 11}, {5, 0, 7, 2, 9}, {0, 7, 2}}
> ```

Related:

- [Is there a built in function to obtain the back diagonal of a matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23240/121)

Answer (score 7):

```
reverseDiagonal[mA_, x_] := With[{mR = Reverse@mA},
  Diagonal[mR, #] & /@ Apply[Minus@*Subtract, Position[mR, x], 2]
  ]
reverseDiagonal[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 7}, {9, 10, 11, 12}}, 7]
(* {{10, 7, 4}, {11, 7}} *)
```

You may want to map `Reverse` across the lists in this result.