# How to replace anti diagonal elements of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

I want to assign new values to the anti-diagonal elements of a square matrix `m` with the values of its diagonal elements. For that, I want to make use of [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html), with the fact that

> Part position specifications can be patterns

as stated in the documentation.

I want to use a command like this:

```mathematica
ReplacePart[m, (*pattern goes here*) :> Diagonal[m]〚i〛]
```

I need help with writing a pattern to access the anti-diagonal elements.

They have the property of `i+j=Length[m]+1` but I can't find a way to implement it into a pattern match.

For example, with

```
m={
  {100, 9, 3, 8, 0},
  {4, 200, 6, 4, 9},
  {5, 2, 300, 7, 8},
  {7, 9, 6, 400, 5},
  {6, 1, 4, 2, 500}
}
```

I want to produce the matrix

```
{
  {100, 9, 3, 8, 100},
  {4, 200, 6, 200, 9},
  {5, 2, 300, 7, 8},
  {7, 400, 6, 400, 5},
  {500, 1, 4, 2, 500}
}
```

Comment: use the replacement rule `{i_, j_} /; j == Dimensions[m][[2]] + 1 - i :> Diagonal[m][[i]]`?

Comment: Well I am a bit new to conditions and pattern matching. I didn't know how to write it down..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the kind of question that might trigger the "how-many-ways-can-you-do-it" game. I'll kick it off with this:

```
MapIndexed[ReplacePart[#1, -#2 -> #1[[#2[[1]]]]] &, m]
```

Explanation: The index of each row corresponds to the element that should be used as replacement as well as the one to be replaced (just count from the end). So, that suggested using MapIndexed. Then it's a matter of figuring out how to put the MapIndexed arguments into ReplacePart.

Comment: The `ReplacePart[]`+`MapIndexed[]` is a good idea. Here's a slightly more compact version: `ReplacePart[m, MapIndexed[Join[#2, -#2] -> #1 &, Diagonal[m]]]`.

Comment: That’s excellent!

Answer (score 8):

From *The Procedural Dodo*:

If you can do it in place (destroying the orginal `m`), this will be fast:

```
Do[m[[i, -i]] = m[[i, i]], {i, Length@m}]
```

If `m` is a small matrix as in the example, then speed won't matter, but the code is easy to read.

To preserve `m`, use another variable:

```
m2 = m;
Do[m2[[i, -i]] = m2[[i, i]], {i, Length@m2}]
```

It's still relatively fast, but now `m` has to be copied.

Answer (score 6):

Using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[Association[Thread[Map[{# + 1, Length[m] - #} &, Range[0, Length[m] - 1]] -> Diagonal[m]]]][m] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- We can subtract the anti-diagonal to remove it and then add the `Reverse` of diagonal.

```
m = {{100, 9, 3, 8, 0}, {4, 200, 6, 4, 9}, {5, 2, 300, 7, 8}, {7, 9, 
    6, 400, 5}, {6, 1, 4, 2, 500}};
antiDiagonal = Reverse[DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@Reverse[m, {2}], {2}];
reverseDiagonal = Reverse[DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@m, {2}];
m - antiDiagonal + reverseDiagonal
% // MatrixForm
```

[image]

- Or we can at first `Reverse` the matrix `m` to get the `rm` and subtract the `Diagonal` of `rm` and then `Reverse`.

```
m = {{100, 9, 3, 8, 0}, {4, 200, 6, 4, 9}, {5, 2, 300, 7, 8}, {7, 9, 
    6, 400, 5}, {6, 1, 4, 2, 500}};
rm = Reverse[m, {2}];
Reverse[rm - DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@rm + 
  DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@m, {2}]
% // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 4):

use element-wise operation.

1. keep the diag-matrix and reverse it.

```
anti = mat //
Diagonal // (*take diag*)
DiagonalMatrix // (*make mat*)
Map[Reverse] (*rev it*)
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 100}, {0, 0, 0, 200, 0}, {0, 0, 300, 0, 0}, {0, 400, 0, 0, 0}, {500, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

2. make the mask mat

```
mask = IdentityMatrix[Length@mat]// (*np.eye*)
Map[Reverse] // (*rev*)
1-#& (*mask*)
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}

3. mask it then add anti

```
mat * mask + anti
```

> {{100, 9, 3, 8, 100}, {4, 200, 6, 200, 9}, {5, 2, 300, 7, 8}, {7, 400, 6, 400, 5}, {500, 1, 4, 2, 500}}

Answer (score 4):

```
idm = IdentityMatrix[Length@m]
(res = Reverse /@ (m idm) + m (-(Reverse /@ idm ) + 1)
  ) // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 100 & 9 & 3 & 8 & 100 \\
 4 & 200 & 6 & 200 & 9 \\
 5 & 2 & 300 & 7 & 8 \\
 7 & 400 & 6 & 400 & 5 \\
 500 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 500 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

```
With[
  {mask = 
     Reverse[ReplaceAll[DiagonalMatrix[Function /@ Diagonal[m]], 0 -> Identity], 2]},
  MapThread[Construct, {mask, m}, 2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Making use of the [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92670/106) posted by [ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao) (in an answer to [How to zero (or replace) the diagonal of a square matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92666/106))

```
With[{rm=Reverse@m, dr=Reverse@Diagonal@m},

    (UpperTriangularize[rm,1] + LowerTriangularize[rm,-1] + DiagonalMatrix[dr])//Reverse

    ]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 100 & 9 & 3 & 8 & 100 \\
 4 & 200 & 6 & 200 & 9 \\
 5 & 2 & 300 & 7 & 8 \\
 7 & 400 & 6 & 400 & 5 \\
 500 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 500 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Alternatively:

```
Reverse[UpperTriangularize[Reverse@m,1] + LowerTriangularize[Reverse@m,-1]] + 
SparseArray[Band[{1, 5}, Automatic, {1, -1}] -> Diagonal[m], {5, 5}]

(*
{
 {100, 9, 3, 8, 100}, 
 {4, 200, 6, 200, 9}, 
 {5, 2, 300, 7, 8}, 
 {7, 400, 6, 400, 5}, 
 {500, 1, 4, 2, 500}
} 
*)
```

Also related:

[Is there a built in function to obtain the back diagonal of a matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23240/106)

Answer (score 2):

```
m =
  {{100, 9, 3, 8, 0},
   {4, 200, 6, 4, 9},
   {5, 2, 300, 7, 8},
   {7, 9, 6, 400, 5},
   {6, 1, 4, 2, 500}};
```

```
With[{d = Diagonal @ m},
  With[{r = Range @ Length @ d},
   ReplacePart[Thread[Transpose[{r, Reverse @ r}] -> d]] @ m]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]